# How to fix error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘asm’, in atmega328p

Tags: avr, arduino-uno

I have written the following code:

```c
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define Set_bit_(PORT,BIT) PORT|=(1<<BIT)
#define Clr_bit_(PORT,BIT) PORT&=~(1<<BIT)
#define OUTPUT 1
#define INPUT 0
#define HIGH 1
#define LOW 0

void Sei();
void cli();

struct {
  volatile unsigned int FLAG_ISR0 : 1;
  volatile unsigned int FLAG_ISR1 : 1;
} FLAG_BIT;

int main(void)
{
}
   
void Sei()
{
  Set_bit_(SREG,7);
}

void cli()
{
  Clr_bit_(SREG, 7);
}
```

Whenever I include the interrupt header, the compiler shows an error in the line with `cli` saying

```
error: expected identifier or '(' before 'asm'
```

Comment: look at header avr/interrupt, there should be already function named cli(). What do you want to do? I mean why do you write your own Sei and cli functions? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<avr/interrupt.h>
```

this file ([source](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/interrupt_8h_source.html)) has the macro `sei()`. Therefore, the line

```
void cli()
```

is expanded as

```
void  __asm__ __volatile__ ("cli" ::: "memory")
```

which is not what you're expecting.

You may use another name for the function (for example, make the name start with capital letter `Cli`, as you did with `Sei`).

But, since those functions do exactly the same what `cli()` and `sei()` macros do, you may want to discard them at all and use the macros instead.